# Webscraping with Python - Empty dataframe

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-analysis

I am trying to web scrape coinmarketcap.com using Selenium with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Ejer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')

Crypto = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS"]')
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="cmc-link"]')
coincap = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="DAY"]')

CMC_list = []
for c in range(len(Crypto)):
    CMC_list.append(Crypto[c].text)

print(CMC_list)

price_list = []
for p in range(len(price)):
    price_list.append(price[p].text)

cap_list = []
for i in range(len(coincap)):
    cap_list.append(coincap[i].text)


data_tuples = list(zip(CMC_list[1:], price_list[1:], cap_list[1:]))
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Coin Name', 'Price', 'Market Cap'])


driver.close()

print(temp_df)
```

However, the dataframe is empty, and I am not sure why. Can someone please help or guide me to the right direction.

Comment: None of your xpaths seem to bring up anything.

Comment: Also coinmarket has an api which you can just use instead.

Comment: But is it because the html code that I am calling is wrong?